# connect to docker mysql from host machine

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose (showing just MySQL part):

```
  site_mysql:
    image: site/mysql:latest
    build: ./images/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      -  site_mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      -  site_appnet
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

I can connect to MySQL from inside the container, but I can't from localhost, the error I'm getting is **Host site_mysql is unknown.**

docker file is:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

MAINTAINER Author

# The official MySQL docker image will run all .sh and .sql scripts found in this directory
# the first time the container is started.
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
# Always use UTC
default-time-zone='+00:00'

# To turn off strict mode (alas, we started out that way, will be work to turn it on)
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max-allowed-packet = 16M

### Per-thread Buffers
sort-buffer-size = 2M
read-buffer-size = 128K
read-rnd-buffer-size = 256K
join-buffer-size = 256K

### Temp Tables
tmp-table-size = 64M
max-heap-table-size = 64M

#### Storage Engines
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb = FORCE
```

init.sql :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS site;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS site_test;
CREATE USER 'site'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON site.* TO 'site'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I'm using the same configuration for a while with different projects and all was okay until now. Any ideas why my host can't recognize `site_mysql`?

**Updated**

Also, I have :

```
  site_memcached:
    image: memcached:1.4-alpine
    networks:
      -  videosite_appnet
```

and here I can connect using `site_memcached` as a name of the host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect from your host computer you have to use "localhost" instead of "site_mysql"

```
site_mysql: --> this is the servername within docker
    image: site/mysql:latest
    build: ./images/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      -  site_mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      -  site_appnet
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" --> here you open 
          port 3306 also on localhost (your host computer)
          and bind it to the containers port 3306
```

My personal config (mac host) is: ( maybe "restart: always" helps)

```
db:
    image: "mysql:5"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - main
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d:cached
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:cached
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword
```

Comment: Actually, I already tried to use `localhost` and also can't connect, and I tried to bind to different port like `33066:3306` and also not working. Right now on my machine, I have two more projects on docker (all containers are down so here can't be any conflicts) with same configurations  and all is working when I'm using server name from docker compose there

Comment: `db:
    image: "mysql:5"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - main
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d:cached
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:cached
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword`

thats my config. maybe "restart: always" helps

Answer (score 1):

To connect from Host to mySQL, Use below command

```
docker exec -it mysql_container-name mysql -uroot -p
```

“root” is the username for MySQL database.

Comment: in such way, I'm still connecting from docker container, but I need the ability to connect from the host machine using, for example, MySQL workbench and as in my case I want to have the ability to run laravel command from host machine like `php artisan migrate`, And as I already mentioned few times it's not working only in this project....